# Issue with accessing a CoreData attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm saving a certain attribute `name` in core-data like so..

```
//Saving to CoreData
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
       return
}
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Category", in: managedContext)

let category = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

category.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "theName")

do {
try managedContext.save()
self.mangObjArr.append(category as! Category)

} catch let error as NSError {
print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Now I want to get this `name` in another viewcontroller so that I can pass it as a parameter in an API call. But how I can get the nameattribute that I'm not able to figure out.
Also, I'm not so good at Swift hence asking the question...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should some good tutorials on **`Core Data`**, since this is a very basic question. I don't think you have googled before asking question here. I'll give you the solution, but don't repeat it again.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Category")
if let fetchedObjects = try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest), !fetchedObjects.isEmpty
{
    let category = fetchedObjects.first as? NSManagedObject
    print(category?.value(forKey: "theName"))
}
```

**Links:**

https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-25068

Comment: Thank you, @PGDev..your answer was very helpful. Just one more concern(please excuse me...:)). I'm also getting from an API response an 'id'. But this id does not have an attribute in the xcdatamodel. So how can I save it in the database..? will I have to make another attribute for this 'id'..? Thanks once again...

Comment: You have to make a new attribute for that. Any value is saved in an entity in Core Data corresponding to an attribute only.

Comment: Ok...so you are saying that if I want to save the id as I mentioned, I'll have to write the entire saving in coredata method that was mentioned in the question and then do the retrieval as in your answer ...?

Comment: Yes right. Also, instead of using keyPaths to store and retrieve attributes, create a subclass of NSManagedObject  corresponding to category and use its properties directly. Refer to a tutorial to know what I am trying to convey.

Comment: OK...just one more doubt... while saving such data like 'id' do I need to always add them to an array while saving into core-data...?

Comment: Is your ‘id’ a single element or an array? You can store the data according to your requirement.

Comment: Then you don’t need array for that.